# How to use a tensorflow-lite model in tensorflow for java

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Is it possible to load tensorflow lite models  with tensorflow for java?

I've testet the `SavedModleBundle` and `org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef`
but it doesnt work.

By loading the GraphDef there is a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid GraphDef` exception.

It looks like the tflite interpreter was not implemented for tensorflow for java.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use tensorflow model on standalone java(not in android), you have to use `SavedModleBundle` and you need to compile with java compiler as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_java#tensorflow_with_the_jdk).  For that you need TensorFlow Jar Archive (JAR) and Java Native Interface (JNI) file from tensorflow.

It is not possible to use `tflite` model in standalone java applications.Tensorflow Lite is specifically used for mobile and embedded devices.